# Is there a Woocommerce Subscription function that triggers actions based on subscription status?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, email-client, woocommerce-subscriptions

I use a Wordpress email plugin called Mailster.  I would like to set it up so that if a user cancels their Woocommerce Subscription, or puts it on pause or suspends it, they are moved to a different email list.

I have a code from Mailster itself that executes the list change.  The code is below.

```
add_action( 'my_custom_action', function( ) {
    
    if( $subscriber = mailster( 'subscribers' )->get_by_wpid() ){
        $list_id_from = 1;
        $list_id_to = 2;

        mailster( 'subscribers' )->unassign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_from );
        mailster( 'subscribers' )->assign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_to );
     }
    
});
```

What I need to figure out is how to integrate this with Woocommerce Subscriptions so that when the subscription status is changed (cancelled, paused, active, suspended), the code above is triggered.

I'm really not sure how to approach it.  I know there's a couple of hooks

```
"woocommerce_order_status_changed" and "woocommerce_subscription_status_updated"
```

But I have no idea how to incorporate them into a functional code.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that with a little modification I made to the code, it works.  Below is the full code that I've used.

```
function moved_to_a_different_email_list_when_subscription_status_updated( $subscription, $new_status, $old_status ){
    if( $subscriber = mailster( 'subscribers' )->get_by_wpid() ){
        $list_id_from = 5;
        $list_id_to = 6;
        if( $new_status == 'cancelled' || $new_status == 'pending-cancel' ){
            mailster( 'subscribers' )->unassign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_from );
            mailster( 'subscribers' )->assign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_to );
        }
     }
}
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'moved_to_a_different_email_list_when_subscription_status_updated', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code. you can use `add_action` to use `woocommerce_order_status_changed` and `woocommerce_subscription_status_updated` action hooks.

```
function moved_to_a_different_email_list_when_order_status_changed( $order_id, $previous_status, $next_status, $WC_Order ) { 
    if( $subscriber = mailster( 'subscribers' )->get_by_wpid() ){
        $list_id_from = 1;
        $list_id_to = 2;
        if( $next_status == 'cancelled' ){
            mailster( 'subscribers' )->unassign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_from );
        }else{
            mailster( 'subscribers' )->assign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_to );
        }
     }
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'moved_to_a_different_email_list_when_order_status_changed', 10, 4 ); 

function moved_to_a_different_email_list_when_subscription_status_updated( $subscription, $new_status, $old_status ){
    if( $subscriber = mailster( 'subscribers' )->get_by_wpid() ){
        $list_id_from = 1;
        $list_id_to = 2;
        if( $new_status == 'cancelled' ){
            mailster( 'subscribers' )->unassign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_from );
        }else{
            mailster( 'subscribers' )->assign_lists( $subscriber->ID, $list_id_to );
        }
     }
}
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_status_updated', 'moved_to_a_different_email_list_when_subscription_status_updated', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'm trying to go through the code to figure out exactly where to put the specific status.  Like where is the actual subscription status like "cancelled?"  Where would that go in the code?  Also in the first part of the code, I notice there's a $this_get_id and $instance, I'm not really sure what those are?  Do they need to be changed to something?  I apologize if this seems obvious I just don't have much experience with these things.

Comment: Check my edits. `$this_get_id` is `$order_id` and `$instance` is `$WC_Order` object.

Comment: Thank you!  Now it makes a little more sense to me.  But just a couple of more things.  1) where it says $order_ID and $WC_order in the first part, do I need to replace those with ID number of the order?  Or do they need to be included in part of the code like `if($order_ID="something)`?

Then in the second part, do I need to include the $old_status somewhere?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this code. can you explain more about this?

Comment: I have a membership website that people can gain/lose access to using Woocommerce Subscriptions.  When they are successfully subscribed, they are automatically placed inside a newsletter email list (list A).  All I want is when they cancel or pause their subscription from their account, that they are moved to a new list (List B).  

Then if they decide to rejoin or renew their subscription, they are moved back into List A.  That's pretty much it.

Comment: So that's means if the order is cancelled or the subscription status is cancelled you want to remove a user from the list? and other cases you want to add them to the list?

Comment: Yeah exactly.  I just want to move them to a different list based on their subscription status.  So like in the original Mailster code there's a "list_ID_from" and a "list_ID_to"